# How to prevent running out of disk space?

Tags: ssh, disk-usage

Often an automated process will completely fill up the main drive and I won't even be able to login over SSH to fix it.  How do I prevent all the space from being used, so that I can always login to my headless server with SSH and delete something?

```
can't create socket: No space left on device
```

(There are an infinite number of things that could fill space. A good answer will not care which of them is doing it, but will prevent them from using the space that ssh needs to function.)

Comment: Allocate more space; cron a job to autoremove; autoclean or remove whatever is being fills your disk space.  You haven't provided any detail as to what is filling the space, so we cannot offer you much.

Comment: It's something that has never happened to me. I have ~10 Linux computers at home, and ~20 or so at work. Sure, I've had full disks, so full that dhcpd stopped working, but I've been able to login via ssh to clean up...

Comment: It's often the log and cache files that fill up disks. This can be prevented by giving `/var` an own file system, so that logs can't fill up `/`.

Comment: @guiverc It doesn't matter what's filling up the space. What's important is that it shouldn't be possible to take up so much that ssh no longer functions.

Comment: Interestingly, I just realized that SFTP still works, even though SSH console doesn't, so I was able to delete some files over SFTP and then SSH started working again.

Answer (score 2):

Several Linux filesystems, including the most common one `ext4`, have a feature to deal with this exact problem: by default 5% of the space on the drive is reserved for the root user. This ensures the administrator can always log in to fix out-of-space problems.

TL/DR:

1. Enable the root account in Ubuntu
2. Configure the SSH daemon to allow root login
3. Login with the root account whenever lack of space is preventing normal login

A security note is in order: allowing root logins should be done with care. In particular, it's recommended to allow root login via certificates only, no password logins allowed. In any case, make sure when you define the root password to make it a strong one (it should rarely be needed interactively anyway, so go to town on the password length).

Comment: Is there no way to do something similar for my user account?

Comment: @endolith No, the reserved space is always for the root account.

Answer (score -2):

Well first try to figure out what is filling up your space. Try to remove any bloatware or background processes which might be filling up your space.
You can use: `sudo iotop -a` or any `df` commands.
Then if there is necessary application which can't be stopped then make a cron job or a habit of regular cleanup of cache and temprary files.
There are many ways to clear up your cache.Try: 
`du -sh /var/cache/apt/archives`
`sudo apt-get clean`
`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`
`sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
`sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` 
`sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`